# Select parents with specific children in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database structure with 2 types, that looks like this:

```
Project
     ProjectID
     ProjectName

Task
     TaskID
     TaskTitle
     Status
     ProjectID
```

Because of all the relations declared on the sql server - the dbml automatically knows about them, and I can get all project's tasks simply by:

```
myProject.Tasks
```

So far so good.

I want to display all the projects and their tasks, so the user can filter them by Status.
Which means that I want to display only those tasks (and their project, of course), that meets the selected criteria.

For that I have a Repeater, that look somewhat like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptProjects" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Eval("ProjectName") %> (<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>):
                  <asp:Repeater id="rptTasks" DataSource="<%#(Container.DataItem as Project).Tasks %>" runat="server">                          
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <%# Eval("TaskTitle") %>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I can't figure out the LINQ query needed.

In each of the queries I tried, I get the projects alright (meaning that if none of the project's task meets the selected criteria it's not on the list), but every time `Project.Tasks` hold *all* the tasks for the selected project, and never a filtered tasks list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only do you need to filter the projects queryable itself, you need to project the `Tasks` relationship to a new one with the given condition:

```
var query = context.Projects.Where(project => 
        project.Tasks.Any(task => task.Status == someStatus)
    .Select(project => new
    {
        project.ProjectName,
        Tasks = project.Tasks.Where(task => task.Status == someStatus),
    });
```

Note that, because of this change, you'll need to change the data source of the inner repeater to `Eval("Tasks")` rather than what you have.

Comment: Well, that works better then ever before :)

Is there a way to covert to a list of something other then anonymous type?
Other way then to write a new class that holds PtojectName and Tasks, that is.

Comment: @yanivca Sure, just create new items of some other type than an anonymous type...but in this particular context you probably don't need a named type.

Answer (score 0):

```
var TasksForProject = from p in Project
join t in Tasks on p.ProjectID equals t.ProjectID
where t.Satus !=null and t.status==SomeStatus
select new {
p,t
}
```

After that you can take this into memory using tolist() and then you can groupby on the basis of properties.